# how to convert from python to matlab - a*dx.min( )/abs(v) -

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to rewrite a python script into matlab and I don't really understand the last line here:

```
a = 1
v = 0.5
nx = 32
x  = sp.linspace(-2.,2.,nx)  
dx = (max(x)-min(x))/nx
dt =  a*dx.min( )/abs(v)
```

I am struggling with the `dt` definition. In the code `a, dx` and `v` are real numbers. Why is there a `.min` and why is the bracket empty?

I am sorry for my ignorance, but I am really new to python.

Comment: Please post a *complete* minimal reproducer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It is very hard to help with incomplete information ...

Comment: I have edited the problem, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: x is actually a vector, dx is obviously a scalar and in y it seems that a must be multiplied by the minimum value in dx... which sounds weird since it's a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

the code for min() means to output the min value of that object, otherwise you'll just get it's type (`function float64.min`.)
because `dx` is a scalar taking it's minimal value is meaningless, it has only one value to begin with.
the conversion you seek should be:

`dt =  a*min(dx)./abs(v)`

Answer (score 0):

This python code is invalid. It should not run because ints do not have function attributes.

Result: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'min'`

Comment: This is more of a comment than of an answer. An answer would answer the OP's question, which is _how to convert..._.

Comment: Yes, let's show the OP how to write invalid MATLAB code.